# Rails view templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templating-engine

Besides [Markaby](http://redhanded.hobix.com/inspect/markabyForRails.html) and [Haml](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/), are there any better Rails View Templating mechanisms?

Comment: - Better than what? ERb? - And better according to which criteria?

Comment: Why is your question tagged RJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [Vida Hokstad's site](http://www.hokstad.com/mini-reviews-of-19-ruby-template-engines.html):

1. [Radius](http://radius.rubyforge.org/)
2. [cs/Template](http://cstemplate.rubyforge.org/)
3. [eRuby](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/eruby/)
4. [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/)
5. [Galena](http://galena.rubyforge.org/)
6. [Tenjin](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/)
7. [Ruty](http://ruty.rubyforge.org/documentation/)
8. [PageTemplate](http://pagetemplate.org/)
9. [Amrita](http://amrita.sourceforge.jp/)
10. [Amrita2](http://retro.brain-tokyo.net/projects/amrita2/blog)
11. [Kwartz](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/kwartz/)
12. [Maline](http://www.malline.org/)
13. [Builder:XMLMarkup](http://builder.rubyforge.org/)
14. [RedCloth](http://whytheluckystiff.net/ruby/redcloth/)
15. [BlueCloth](http://www.deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth)
16. [RSmarty](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rsmarty/)
17. [Tempura](http://rubyforge.org/projects/tempura/)
18. [TAL](http://rubyforge.org/projects/tal/)
19. [Curtis/Punk](http://rubyforge.org/projects/curtis/)
20. [Erby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/erby/)
21. [RBML](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rbml/)
22. [RTALS](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rtals/)
23. [Tie](http://rubyforge.org/projects/tie/)
24. [RVelocity](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rvelocity/)
25. [RailTags](http://rubyforge.org/projects/railtags/)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Hobo's DRYML

Answer (score 0):

You can find the up to date list at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/template_engines